# Confusion with increment operator

Tags: java

```
public class F {
    int test(int e) {
        System.out.println("ok");
        return e;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int y = 8;
        F f = new F();
        int i = f.test(y++);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

the output of this program is `8`, which is what I expect.

```
public class Sa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 8;
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

For this program, the output is `9`, which is surprising: why we are getting different values using the same values and the same increment operator in both programs?

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: You can do the following: 1) try to use a breakpoint to debug; 2) google; 3) make your question better looking. The current post shows virtually none effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`y++` post-increments. That means it increments *after* the expression is evaluated.

When you run

```
i=f.test(y++)
```

then the value passed into the test method is the one before the increment took place.

In your other code sample `i++` is evaluated by itself so the increment takes place before the println.

Change the code in your first sample to `++y` and you should get 9.

Answer (score 1):

`i++` is a *postincrement* operator, which means that it evaluates to the current value of i and then increments *after* use.

I would expect

```
int i = 8
System.out.println(i++);
System.out.println(i);
```

would print `8` then `9`.

You might have meant `++i` which is *preincrement*

Answer (score 0):

**y++ is  post-increment.**

It pass the value and then increments.So you are getting the previous value before incrementing.

In second case you are printing  the incremented value.

Answer (score 0):

`y++` in the

```
i=f.test(y++)
```

is evaluated after the `test()` method is run. So, the test gets the value `8` and prints `8`.

Incrementing it in the `Sa` class is equal to:

```
i++; //     is equal to i+=1     OR i = i + 1;
```

But, that is not why we use the incrementation (`++`). The purpose of it is the **side-effect** that it has in an expression.

Exactly in your example, you want to pass in the 8, but increment it to 9 after the `test` has been executed.